# Terraform escape special char

Tags: terraform

I have to pass a password through terraform which has special characters including backslash.

Terraform apply resulted in following error

27:      "project.plugin.NodeExecutor.WinRMexe.pass" = "j7FUBa&:9"

The symbol ":" is not a valid escape sequence selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable as string, I am using terraform 0.12 and I did as follow.

vars.tf:

```
variable "test" {
  type = string
  default = "j7FUBa&:9"
}
```

output.tf

```
output "mytest" {
  value = var.test
}
```

Now you could see the result using terraform apply:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

mytest = j7FUBa&:9
```

Comment: I am sorry, my password has character "\". I haven't noticed stackoverflow changed the "\" to "&". However, I tried using variable as you mentioned, I still have the same issue.

Comment: "j7FUBa\\:9" - I tried adding a "\" , terraform ran successfully but the value updated to "j7FUBa\\\:"

Comment: you need to say in the variable the type is string

Comment: variable "foo" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = "j7FUBa&\\:9"
}   I have defined the variable as string and tried, which resulted in error.

Comment: you need to try with variable "foo" { type = "string" default = "j7FUBa&:9" }